# Output assets within a matrix block using Imager and Craft 3

Tags: assets, matrix, plugin-imager

I'm having trouble trying to output assets from an Assets field that's within a Matrix block, using Imager. The code below is only outputting the first image that has been added, over and over for each asset, rather outputting each different asset. What am I doing wrong?

I did try changing `{% set logo = block.logos.first() %}` to `{% set logo = block.logos.all() %}`, but that gave me an internal server error.

```
{% for block in entry.modules.all() %}

  {% if block.type == "logosBlock" %}

    {% for image in block.logos %}

        <div class="logo-child">

          {% set logo = block.logos.first() %}
          {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(logo, { width: 312, height: 200, }) %}
          <img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" alt="{{ logo.title }}">
        </div>

      {% endfor %}

    </div>

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you try to fetch the image multiple times?

```
{% for image in block.logos %}
```

Will fetch the images and loop them `{% set logo = block.logos.first() %}` -> will fetch the first image again and again.

```
{% for image in block.logos %}
    {% set transformedImage = craft.imager.transformImage(image, { width: 312, height: 200, }) %}
    <img src="{{ transformedImage.url }}" alt="{{ logo.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Should work